# psycopg2.connect issue after DatabaseError

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

After the DatabaseError is catched (try-except block) the previous data in the table is deleted. I cannot figure out this strange behaviour.

this is the code I used

```
def copy_from_stringio(df, table):
    
    conn = None
    
    try:
        # read database configuration
        params = config()
        # connect to the PostgreSQL database
        conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
        # create a new cursor
        cur = conn.cursor()
        # save dataframe to an in memory buffer
        buffer = StringIO()
        df.to_csv(buffer, index=False, header=False,sep=';')
        buffer.seek(0)
    
        #cursor = conn.cursor()
        cur.copy_from(buffer, table, sep=";")
        conn.commit()
        print("copy_from_stringio() done")
        cur.close()
        
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()
```

Comment: This is not enough information for anyone to help you. You should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), a full copy of the error, and an idea of what the data looks like.

Comment: When data is not compliant with the table schema (such as not null camp being null) the table is erased from previous data uploaded

Comment: 1)  `copy_from` uses [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) and `COPY` is all or none. If there is any error the whole statement roles back. 2) If want partial data loads then you will need to use `INSERT` with `try/except`  to catch each error and commit on success and rollback on error.

Comment: "If there is any error the whole statement roles back" I'd understand a rollback to previous state not deleting the entire data already uploaded into the table. I don't get this behaviour

Comment: 1) Then you will have to show proof of that as the code you show will not do that. Is this code part of bigger process? 2)  Are you sure `params = config()` is grabbing the correct connection information?  3) I would also suggest tailing the the Postgres log file to see what is actually hitting the database.

Comment: Please make you example runnable by supplying imports, and code constructing a minimal `df`.  (and of course testing it to make sure it still does what you say).